# Hibernate does not create foreign key in tables in bidirectional one-to-one relation

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, bidirectional

These are my classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private T id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "core_users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends BaseEntity<Long> implements UserDetails {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_customers")
public class BaseCustomer extends User {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_address")
public class Address extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "owner"))
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BaseCustomer owner;

}
```

When i start the application to create table, in create table but does not create foreign keys in `app_customers` and `app_address`.

Answer (score 0):

Joneid inheritance is not using foreign keys. Read more: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance